# JQuery Object Object Error

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to save the value of the last breadcrumb value to a javascript variable using this JQuery code to get the last breadcrumb value:

```
$('ul li.breadcrumbs:last')
```

I can control the styling of the last breadcrumb value with the above code but when I try to save the value to a variable I just get [object Object].

When I type: `console.dir($('ul.breadcrumbs li:last'));`
into the console I see the two values below, which is the breadcrumb text I want, listed but i'm not sure how to assign them to a variable?

```
innerHTML: "Travel Systems"

innerText: "Travel Systems"
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: `$('ul li.breadcrumbs:last').text()`

Comment: Tried that but it just returned an empty string

Answer (score 0):

Just get the text and store it in a variable via the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) functions :

```
// You can use text() or html() to get the respective content in your variable
var breadcrumb = $('ul li.breadcrumbs:last').text();
```

Or if you have multiple elements, you could map the properties that you needed to an array via the [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function :

```
var breadcrumbs = $('ul li.breadcrumbs:last').map(function() {
    // Access the property that you need from each element here
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: I tried var breadcrumb = $('ul li.breadcrumbs:last').text(); but it returns an empty string?

Comment: You may want to try `html()` instead of text. What does your markup look like?

Comment: html returned undifined. Here's what i see:

Comment: Here's what i see when i type: console.dir($('ul.breadcrumbs li:last')); init[1]
0
:li
accessKey:""
assignedSlot:null
attributes:NamedNodeMap
baseURI:"http://www.preciouslittleone.com/products/19/travel-systems/"
childElementCount:0
childNodes:NodeList[1]
children:HTMLCollection[0]
classList:DOMTokenList[0]
className:""
clientHeight:14
clientLeft:0
clientTop:0
clientWidth:83
contentEditable:"inherit"
dataset:DOMStringMap
dir:""
draggable:false
firstChild:text
firstElementChild:null
hidden:false
id:""
innerHTML:"Travel Systems"
innerText:"Travel Systems"

Comment: the breadcrumb text i want to assign to a variable on this page is: "Travel Systems"

Comment: Can you post what your actual markup / HTML looks like? If your console is showing the `innerHTML` property contains "Travel Systems", then using `html()` or `text()` should return that value.